# How come terminal vim take so long to open HTML files?

Tags: vim, terminal, html-files

I've been using terminal vim with custom plugin for a long-time. I never can wrap my head around this, I've been searching the web for a few days but had no luck.

I do a lot of web development, I use other IDE as well. They open HTML files almost instantly but in terminal vim it takes about anywhere from 5-15 seconds to open a .html file.

Question 1: Is there a reason for that?

Question 2: Are there any ways to improve the performance without resorting to using a separate IDE/editor?

**My Setup**

**OS:** MacOSX Yosemite

**Vim:** Terminal Vim 7.4

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jul 18 2015 22:24:23)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-712
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         -gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o vim        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python   -lruby.2.0.0 -lobjc
```

**.vimrc** (Something in here is causing it)

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
let g:molokai_original = 1
let g:rehash256 = 1
colorscheme molokai 

runtime bundles/tplugin_vim/macros/tplugin.vim

let g:nodejs_complete_config = {
\  'max_node_compl_len': 15
\}

" automatically open and close the popup menu / preview window
au CursorMovedI,InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif

set number
set showcmd
set showmode
set showmatch
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set ai si
set autoindent
set copyindent
set ignorecase
set incsearch 
set hlsearch
set laststatus=2
set mouse=a
if has("mouse")
    set mouse=a
endif

" ------------------------------------------------------------------------
"  Keyboard mappings
" ------------------------------------------------------------------------

map zz :w<CR>
map zx :wq!<CR>
map <c-x> dd
map <c-d> yy p
map <C-2> <C-w> v

" ------------------------------------------------------------------------
" JavaScript related tools
" ------------------------------------------------------------------------

"let JSHintUpdate=1
"let JSHintUpdateWriteOnly=1
"au FileType javascript call JavaScriptFold()

" ------------------------------------------------------------------------
" Control-P settings
" ------------------------------------------------------------------------

" ignore the directories and files with the following extensions
set wildignore+=*/node_modules/*,/*bower_components/*,*/lib/*,*/vendor/*,*/dist/**,*.so,*.swp,*.zip

"au FileType javascript call JavaScriptFold()
set runtimepath^=~/vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim

" ------------------------------------------------------------------------
" Nerdtree related settings
" ------------------------------------------------------------------------
"autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
"autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTreeType") && b:NERDTreeType == "primary") | q | endif

map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" ------------------------------------------------------------------------
" Autoformat plugins - used to format source files
" Supported format: js css html 
" ------------------------------------------------------------------------
noremap <C-f> :Autoformat<CR>

" stylus css pre-processor
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.styl set filetype=stylus

" ------------------------------------------------------------------------
" Airline Configuration
" ------------------------------------------------------------------------

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

let g:airline_detect_modified=1
"let g:airline_powerline_fonts=1
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
"let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
```

**vim --startuptime vim.log** index.html

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.037  000.037: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.130  000.093: Allocated generic buffers
000.419  000.289: locale set
000.424  000.005: clipboard setup
000.432  000.008: window checked
000.875  000.443: inits 1
001.015  000.140: parsing arguments
001.021  000.006: expanding arguments
003.795  002.774: shell init
004.063  000.268: Termcap init
004.087  000.024: inits 2
004.209  000.122: init highlight
004.848  000.391  000.391: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
011.945  000.201  000.201: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
012.101  000.593  000.392: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
030.690  000.163  000.163: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/mustache.vim/ftdetect/mustache.vim
030.847  000.050  000.050: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/node/ftdetect/node.vim
031.072  000.116  000.116: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/tern_for_vim/ftdetect/tern.vim
031.435  000.224  000.224: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script/ftdetect/coffee.vim
031.573  000.048  000.048: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-jade/ftdetect/jade.vim
031.694  000.048  000.048: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript-syntax/ftdetect/javascript.vim
031.856  000.082  000.082: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-json/ftdetect/json.vim
031.983  000.056  000.056: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-less/ftdetect/less.vim
032.200  000.085  000.085: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-stylus/ftdetect/stylus.vim
032.414  020.086  019.214: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
032.482  021.231  000.552: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
032.694  000.013  000.013: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
032.963  000.046  000.046: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
033.301  000.043  000.043: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
033.866  000.167  000.167: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
034.505  000.180  000.180: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
034.981  000.176  000.176: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
035.593  002.210  001.687: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/colors/molokai.vim
036.112  031.732  007.798: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
036.128  000.187: sourcing vimrc file(s)
036.937  000.669  000.669: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/plugin/taglist.vim
037.200  000.115  000.115: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/command-t/plugin/command-t.vim
037.763  000.232  000.232: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/autoload/ctrlp/mrufiles.vim
037.944  000.620  000.388: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/plugin/ctrlp.vim
040.163  002.101  002.101: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/emmet-vim/plugin/emmet.vim
040.358  000.064  000.064: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/jshint.vim/plugin/jshint.vim
040.514  000.034  000.034: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/jshint2.vim/plugin/jshint2.vim
045.684  005.030  005.030: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdcommenter/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim
046.721  000.391  000.391: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim
048.165  000.605  000.605: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim
048.410  000.136  000.136: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_controller.vim
048.599  000.091  000.091: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_item.vim
048.821  000.128  000.128: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/key_map.vim
049.202  000.289  000.289: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim
049.605  000.300  000.300: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_file_node.vim
050.096  000.394  000.394: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim
050.442  000.228  000.228: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/opener.vim
050.793  000.245  000.245: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/creator.vim
050.949  000.040  000.040: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/refresh_notifier.vim
051.131  000.073  000.073: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/flag_set.vim
051.263  000.038  000.038: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim
051.584  000.231  000.231: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/ui.vim
052.219  000.531  000.531: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim
068.790  000.104  000.104: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
069.283  000.457  000.457: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
069.780  023.979  019.698: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
070.020  000.135  000.135: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/node/plugin/node.vim
070.694  000.430  000.430: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/ns9tks-vim-l9/autoload/l9.vim
071.913  000.389  000.389: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/ns9tks-vim-autocomplpop/autoload/acp.vim
072.086  001.938  001.119: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/ns9tks-vim-autocomplpop/plugin/acp.vim
072.383  000.181  000.181: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/ns9tks-vim-l9/plugin/l9.vim
072.845  000.036  000.036: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/autoloclist.vim
072.900  000.022  000.022: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/balloons.vim
072.953  000.022  000.022: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/checker.vim
073.019  000.024  000.024: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/cursor.vim
073.098  000.033  000.033: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/highlighting.vim
073.177  000.031  000.031: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/loclist.vim
073.234  000.024  000.024: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/modemap.vim
073.289  000.025  000.025: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/notifiers.vim
073.345  000.025  000.025: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/registry.vim
073.401  000.026  000.026: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/signs.vim
073.949  000.298  000.298: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/autoload/syntastic/util.vim
088.050  000.061  000.061: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/autoloclist.vim
088.156  000.074  000.074: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/balloons.vim
088.331  000.145  000.145: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/checker.vim
088.469  000.108  000.108: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/cursor.vim
088.589  000.092  000.092: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/highlighting.vim
088.913  000.296  000.296: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/loclist.vim
089.052  000.108  000.108: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/modemap.vim
089.157  000.077  000.077: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/notifiers.vim
089.432  000.247  000.247: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/registry.vim
089.568  000.106  000.106: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/signs.vim
090.914  017.484  015.872: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic.vim
091.345  000.246  000.246: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/tlib_vim/plugin/02tlib.vim
092.023  000.294  000.294: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline.vim
092.417  000.129  000.129: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/init.vim
093.038  000.266  000.266: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/parts.vim
093.551  002.072  001.383: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/plugin/airline.vim
093.923  000.235  000.235: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-autoformat/plugin/autoformat.vim
094.203  000.232  000.232: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-autoformat/plugin/defaults.vim
096.491  002.178  002.178: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-bundler/plugin/bundler.vim
103.821  007.158  007.158: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-easymotion/plugin/EasyMotion.vim
110.190  003.721  003.721: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-jsbeautify/plugin/beautifier.vim
111.265  000.912  000.912: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-rails/plugin/rails.vim
111.653  000.079  000.079: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-addon-mw-utils/autoload/funcref.vim
112.043  000.664  000.585: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/plugin/snipMate.vim
112.195  000.039  000.039: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/plugin/vimsnippets.vim
112.923  000.613  000.613: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-surround/plugin/surround.vim
113.126  000.055  000.055: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/VimLint/plugin/vimlint.vim
113.606  000.081  000.081: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
113.878  000.236  000.236: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
114.178  000.265  000.265: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
114.840  000.619  000.619: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
114.917  000.030  000.030: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
115.023  000.051  000.051: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
115.281  000.193  000.193: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
115.444  000.117  000.117: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
115.646  000.159  000.159: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
115.915  000.219  000.219: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
116.406  000.316  000.316: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
116.483  007.326: loading plugins
116.493  000.010: inits 3
116.885  000.392: reading viminfo
116.918  000.033: setting raw mode
116.926  000.008: start termcap
116.981  000.055: clearing screen
122.935  001.477  001.477: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript-syntax/syntax/javascript.vim
123.148  000.052  000.052: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/javascript.vim
126.582  003.017  003.017: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/vb.vim
135.588  008.707  008.707: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/css.vim
2918.472  2782.792  2782.792: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/after/syntax/css.vim
2921.846  2801.535  005.490: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim
2940.443  017.837  017.837: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/css.vim
5725.565  2786.027  2786.027: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/after/syntax/css.vim
8505.199  2780.505  2780.505: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/after/syntax/css.vim
8510.212  5588.892  005.523: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-less/syntax/less.vim
8510.380  000.044  000.044: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/less.vim
8510.475  5589.432  000.496: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-less/after/syntax/html.vim
8510.997  000.024  000.024: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript-syntax/syntax/javascript.vim
8511.133  000.025  000.025: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/javascript.vim
8511.949  001.195  001.146: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script/syntax/coffee.vim
8512.098  001.551  000.356: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script/after/syntax/html.vim
8513.217  000.053  000.053: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/ftplugin/html_snip_helper.vim
8514.333  000.541  000.541: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/autoload/htmlcomplete.vim
8514.542  001.089  000.548: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/html.vim
8516.824  001.671  001.671: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/indent/html.vim
8517.556  000.461  000.461: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script/indent/coffee.vim
8518.012  000.186  000.186: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/indent/html.vim
8518.040  001.134  000.487: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script/after/indent/html.vim
8518.824  000.425  000.425: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions.vim
8519.142  000.077  000.077: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/quickfix.vim
8519.491  000.115  000.115: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/netrw.vim
8520.065  000.175  000.175: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/ctrlp.vim
8520.634  000.101  000.101: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/commandt.vim
8521.232  000.101  000.101: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/syntastic.vim
8521.788  000.161  000.161: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
8525.806  000.158  000.158: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/section.vim
8526.446  000.224  000.224: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim
8528.486  000.112  000.112: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes.vim
8528.786  000.628  000.516: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/molokai.vim
8532.367  000.115  000.115: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/util.vim
8533.192  000.166  000.166: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/builder.vim
8533.740  000.123  000.123: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
8547.486  000.124  000.124: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/node/autoload/node.vim
8552.647  037.508: opening buffers
8553.099  000.233  000.233: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/autoload/ctrlp/utils.vim
8554.960  000.225  000.225: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/syntastic/autoload/syntastic/log.vim
8555.617  002.512: BufEnter autocommands
8555.619  000.002: editing files in windows
8560.534  000.076  000.076: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/deprecation.vim
8560.776  005.081: VimEnter autocommands
8560.783  000.007: before starting main loop
8570.626  009.843: first screen update
8570.628  000.002: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it taking time for only html file or for any other file also it is taking the same time.

Comment: @ali786 as far as I'm aware, its only HTML thus far. I've opened JS file and its almost instant. Stylus files are pretty quick, although CSS is slightly slow but no where near the level of HTML files.

Comment: which flavor of linux you are using have you installed the vim. sometimes pre-installed vim gives trouble

Comment: @ali786 I've updated the question with the setup details.

Comment: possible solution might be try re-installing the vim --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012203/gvim-or-macvim-in-mac-os-x

Comment: @ali786 Thanks for trying to help, I prefer to know why. I'll keep looking, also that suggest using macvim or gvim which is definitely not something I'm after. I use terminal vim due to not having to open or switch around to other windows. Everything I need is in the terminal, I find it more productive this way. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you start vim like this: `vim -u NONE` (not loading any configuration or any plugins) does it still take a long time? Maybe one of the plugins or your configuration is causing the problem.

Comment: @ap0 that is literally instant, I had a feeling it was the plugins as I have quiet a few but I don't know which one nor how to troubleshoot it :(

Comment: This doesn't mean that it's the plugins fault. Remember we disabled plugins and your vimrc. To troubleshoot further use `vim -N --noplugin -i NONE` to only use your vimrc. And `vim -N -u NORC -i NONE` to only start with plugins. Then you will know for sure. Take a look at this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: @ap0 It seems like the first command is causing the slowness, according to the guide its in the .vimrc. (Vim -N --noplugin -i NONE <filename>) I've added my .vimrc file to the question. I'll probably disable line by line and see whats going on. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please also run `vim --startuptime vim.log` and add the files contents to your question?

Comment: @ap0 I've ran the command as requested and uploaded the files content.

Comment: Did you forget to open a html file with the last command? As far as I can see the startuptime was 150 msec. That looks fine. Did you run `vim --startuptime vim.log <somehtmlfile>`?

Comment: @ap0 Yes I did, sorry, its corrected now. I took your command literally, I'm not a vim expert. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26828/discussion-between-thelazychap-and-ap0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the output of `--startuptime` you can see what causes the long startup.

```
2918.472  2782.792  2782.792: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/after/syntax/css.vim
2921.846  2801.535  005.490: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim

5725.565  2786.027  2786.027: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/after/syntax/css.vim
8505.199  2780.505  2780.505: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/after/syntax/css.vim
8510.212  5588.892  005.523: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-less/syntax/less.vim

8510.475  5589.432  000.496: sourcing /Users/<USERNAME>/.vim/bundle/vim-less/after/syntax/html.vim
```

If I understand correctly the files in the `after` directory extend the default syntax files with addition defintitions. A big portion of time gets lost for the vim-less plugin.

Try disableing vim-less plugin and see if loading gets better. Why this is caused by the plugin I don't know though.

Comment: How can I disable a particular plugin? Is there a command I can run to disable it or just completely delete the vim-less folder?

Comment: I took out the css.vim file in the after/syntax/ (not sure why its there in the first place) but its flying. Thank you very much for your help, greatly appreciated, as it was driving me away from VIM (something I love to use).

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888970/how-do-you-disable-a-specific-plugin-in-vim, so put in your vimrc `let g:loaded_vim_less = 1`. I don't know if this would be the correct name for the plugin. Try entering `let g:loaded_` and switch through the names with `Tab` Key. If it does not have the command, deleting the plugin folder is an option too.

Comment: @TheLazyChap it is there because vim-less plugin put it there. It adds additinal highlighting to the default css file.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all plugins, then added and tested, finally found these plugins were the cause of slowness of opening html files:

> 'hail2u/vim-css3-syntax'
>    'mhinz/vim-signify'